# iOS push notification, receives data but no alert screen not displayed

Tags: java, ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement APNs using FCM.
Currently, if  the server includes Notification parameter in the message, I will receive both data and the push notification in foreground and background. However, without Notification parameter and only using Data to send data, I will receive information from didReceiveRemoteNotification but the phone will not display alert notification for user to click on. The function with notification parameter uses userNotificationCenter function and properly display the alert notification.

This is my code for  didReceiveRemoteNotification. I am wondering if I am missing any codes in my part. We are not certain if this is our backend problem or frontend problem.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler:
                 @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    print ("didreceiveremotenoti")
    print ("UIStart",userInfo,"UIFIN")
    guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        completionHandler(.failed)
        return
    }
    print ("APS START",aps,"APSFIN")
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

This is the backend code for creating the json and other things that is currently working for android.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
public class FcmMessageReq {
    private boolean validate_only;
    private Message message;

    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class Message {
        private String token;
        private Data data;
    }

    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    public static class Data {
        private String movingPage;
        private String title;
        private String body;
    }

}
```

Thank you.

EDIT

Here is how FcmMessageReq is used. (I personally do not know the full detail as I am not the backend developer)

```
public void sendMessageToOnePerson(String deviceToken, String title, String body, String movingPage) {
        String message = makeMessage(deviceToken, title, body, movingPage);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody
                .create(message, MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL)
                .post(requestBody)
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + getAccessToken())
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; utf-8")
                .build();

        String errMsg = null;

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            System.out.println(response);

            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                errMsg = response.body().string();
                new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            if (Objects.nonNull(errMsg)) {
                log.error("{}", "Unexpected code " + errMsg);
            }
            log.error("{}", exception.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    private String makeMessage(String deviceToken, String title, String body, String movingPage) {
        FcmMessageReq fcmMessage = FcmMessageReq.builder()
                .validate_only(false)
                .message(
                        FcmMessageReq.Message.builder()
                                .token(deviceToken)
                                .data(
                                        FcmMessageReq.Data.builder()
                                                .movingPage(movingPage)
                                                .title(title)
                                                .body(body)
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .build()
                )

                .build();
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(fcmMessage);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("{}", exception.getStackTrace());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does the guy named 'FcmMessageReq' come into play?

Comment: @ElTomato Hi, I added the code that was used for the function. I believe it is building the message using the variables or some sorts. I am not the backend developer tho. Thank you for consideration.

Comment: I don't know the issue you are addressing.  If you want to show a notification that the user can tap, then you need to use `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`.